# Spring Jdbc Template unexpected behavior with variable in query

Tags: mysql, spring-jdbc

I have a table with id and date column. **Presently, there are 10 records** for each id with different dates. I want to **fetch the latest 3 records for each id**. When I run the query on command line, it works as expected and return exactly 3 records. But when I run the same query with **Spring JDBC Template, it returns all 10 records for each id**.
My query is as below:-

```
SELECT
  `ranked`.`ID`,
  `ranked`.`DATE`
FROM
  (SELECT
    `stk`.`id` AS ID,
    `stk`.`date` AS DATE,
    @id_rank := IF(@current_id = `stk`.`id`,@id_rank + 1,1) AS id_rank,
    @current_id := `stk`.`id`
  FROM
    stack stk
  ORDER BY `stk`.`id` ASC,
    `stk`.`date` DESC) ranked
WHERE ranked.id_rank <= 3
```

My Java Code is like this:-

```
public static final String ID_FILTER_QUERY = "SELECT `ranked`.`ID`, `ranked`.`DATE` FROM "
            + "(SELECT `stk`.`id` AS ID, `stk`.`date` AS DATE, @id_rank := IF(@current_id = `stk`.`id`,@id_rank + 1,1) AS id_rank,"
            + "@current_id := `stk`.`id` FROM stack stk ORDER BY `stk`.`id` ASC, `stk`.`date` DESC) ranked WHERE ranked.id_rank <= 3";

public List<StackDTO> getStackGroupById() {

    return jdbcTemplate.query(Queries.ID_FILTER_QUERY, new IdMapper());
}
```

Is there another way to get the last 3 records for each id or from each group?

Comment: where is java code?

Comment: @JacekCz, added in the question